# Lightning component deployment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, metadata-api, migration-tool, lightning

I have created few lightning component in my GSO ORG and now I want to deploy it to my another ORG

I created a below mentioned package . It is retrieving the lightning components and creating a folder name 'Aura'under the SRC folder in my project(event, bundle etc... are inside that folder). However, when I am trying it to deploy to server, it is giving me this error: 'Unable to Deploy, no deployable resource found'. any Idea how to deploy lightning components?

**Package I created for retrieving the lightning components:**

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
```

Comment: what is the version of your package.xml ?

Comment: I am using 33.0

Comment: Which IDE are you using to deploy this ?ANT or Force.com IDE?

Comment: I am using Force.com IDE, just read here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ that Lightning component can only be deployed from via Managed package.

Comment: will this work https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexible_page_deploy_task.htm  ?

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly fine!! Thankyou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve and deploy all types of Lightning metadata, including Components, Applications, Interfaces, and Events, from/to any org using the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/), by deploying/retrieving the `AuraDefinitionBundle` metadata type.

I have gotten this to work using the **API v35** version of the Force.com Migration Tool --- I don't know whether it works with earlier versions of the tool, but judging by the [Lightning_FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ) incorrectly saying that this is not possible when in fact it *is*, I'd guess that this only works in v33 or higher since Spring 15 (v33) was when Lightning Components went GA.

I have tested deploys to Developer Edition orgs with AND without namespaces, which further makes me think that the Lightning FAQ needs to be updated.

**RETRIEVE**

I did a simple "retrieve unpackaged" routine using the following SF Ant retrieve task:

```
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
      retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
```

With package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```

This dumps retrieved output into a specified folder, putting all Aura bundles within an `aura` folder. Each bundle --- whether it is a Lightning Application, Component, etc. --- will be displayed within a separate child folder within the `aura` folder, with the name of the Bundle. Within each bundle's folder, the individual component pieces of each bundle are retrieved. For instance, if you've got a Lightning Component called "example", you might have the following child files within `retrieveUnpackaged/aura/example`:

- example.cmp (COMPONENT XML)
- example.cmp-meta.xml (META file for Bundle)
- example.css (CSS)
- example.design (DESIGN)
- example.svg (SVG)
- exampleController.js (CONTROLLER)
- exampleHelper.js (HELPER)
- exampleRenderer.js (RENDERER)

[image: aura retrieve file structure]

For other types of Bundles, e.g. Lightning Applications, the `-meta.xml` file will be attached to whatever the Bundle's principal file is, e.g. for a Lightning App named "test" there will be a "test.app-meta.xml` file in the directory.

**DEPLOY**

To deploy this code to another org, I did a "deploy unpackaged" routine using the following SF Ant deploy task:

```
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
      deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
```

Where `retrieveUnpackaged` is the name of the directory that the `sf:retrieve` task dumped its output into, which contains the `aura` folder as well as the following `package.xml` file (again, this is generated automatically by the retrieve task, so no need to modify this at all, I'm only showing it here for illustrative purposes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>page</members>
        <members>example</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```